# How do I do this in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

To remove a 1-second video clip from every 9 seconds in a 6-minute video,if audio also present genarate a ffmpeg code.I am unable to get output can you help us

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: for a example Total video length is 6 minutes .So for every 9seconds 00:00:09 remove 1 second video clip ,so 10th second clip gone and again at  19th second (00:00;19) and remove 1 second clip, so 20th second clip gone..like

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? Do not answer in comments. Add the request info to your question to make it better. Read the Help section to learn how this site works

Comment: See https://video.stackexchange.com/q/17203/

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a single ffmpeg command, but you can create a batch file:

```
@echo off

set "input_file=%~1"
set "output_file=output.mp4"
ffmpeg  -i "%input_file%" -c copy -f segment -segment_time 10 -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 "%input_file%_chunk%%03d.mp4"

set "chunk_number=1"

for %%F in ("%input_file%_chunk*.mp4") do (
   
    ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 00:00:09 -i "%%F" "trimmed_%%~nF.mp4"
    echo file 'trimmed_%%~nF.mp4' >> list.txt
    set /a "chunk_number+=1"

)

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt "%output_file%"

del "%input_file%_chunk*.mp4"
del "trimmed_*.mp4"
del "list.txt"

echo Video processing complete. Output file: %output_file%
pause
```

Just save this as a ".bat" file, and then drag and drop any video onto it.

Comment: What does the "echo ffconcat version 1.0 > list.txt" part do?

Comment: @RicardoBohner You don't actually need it. I edited the answer